# Virtual Window Server 2012 R2 - This PC information?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, windows-server-2012

What do I see if I open the "This PC" > "Properties" on a Virtual Windows Server 2012 R2?

Is it

- the dedicated CPU, RAM a.s.o for the Virtual server

or is it

- information of the physical server which the virtual server is running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still have a Windows Server 2012 VM running on one of my computers from a class I was taking, so I decided to open it up and see exactly what it says. This is in VMware Workstation 10.

[image]

The processor is the physical processor in the computer. I've only given this VM one core, but it recognizes the full 8-core processor. It does only see the 2 GB of memory I've given to it, though.

In the Task Manager, it recognizes the eight-core processor, but it only shows the utilization of the core it was given.

[image]

Comment: That is what I thought, and you confirmed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have not done a Server 2012 virtual machine, but other virtual machines I've done you will see the specs you designated for that virtual machine.

Comment: Ok. The weird thing was that it specified a CPU with such detailed it looked like it was showing hardware information, but I guess it dedicated a CPU core for it.